# How to get GMT time in milliseconds using boost Date_Time?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

Is there a simple way to get from `boost` `Date_Time` library a current `GMT` time in milliseconds?

Here is one example which uses `time_of_day`, I don't want `time_of_day` but **total time in GMT** as `long long int`:

```
boost::posix_time::ptime time =
          boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();
boost::posix_time::time_duration duration( time.time_of_day() );  // ???
long long int timeInMilliseconds = duration.total_milliseconds();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing built-in that I can see, but as usual, it's trivial to implement:

```cpp
boost::posix_time::time_duration::tick_type milliseconds_since_epoch()
{
    using boost::gregorian::date;
    using boost::posix_time::ptime;
    using boost::posix_time::microsec_clock;

    static ptime const epoch(date(1970, 1, 1));
    return (microsec_clock::universal_time() - epoch).total_milliseconds();
}
```

Comment: That's one clean answer!  But can you suggest a way to construct a Boost ptime or date object from milliseconds?

Comment: @Caroline : `ptime` has a constructor taking a `date` and a `time_duration`, and the latter has a named constructor `milliseconds`. Supply an epoch for the date and use the named constructor and you should be set (unless you run into resolution issues).

Answer (score 0):

With C++11, you can

```
//get current millisecond in epoch
auto currentMillis = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();

//get crrent nanosecond in epoch
auto currentNanos = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
```

Comment: I know this question is about using Boost. but, I came here for std solution and found none. so, posting my findings as answer.